# How to convert an image to CSS

Tags: php, html, css, render

Usually it's the other way around, but I'm a special kid.

So I was wondering what the most efficient way was to convert an entire image to a CSS-rendered image, I made a method that would

> Get the image (using PHP's image create from JPEG)
>
> Get the width / height of the image
>
> Loop the height of the image, then in that loop -- loop the width
>
> In width loop, get the color of the current position (current loop iteration / height loop iteration (x,y))
>       Display in a div (width=1px;height=1px;rgb(r,g,b))

But that seems to take a really long time to render, as it's displaying thousands if not millions of divs to render the one image, so I was wondering if there was another way to display an image from getting the `hex / rgb colors` from an image.

In a way -- **Looking for the quickest way to display a pixel of data, I understand a `div` isn't the best for that because it's meant to hold data, etc...**

Comment: Use datauris, base64 . And add it as a background. There are plenty of online converters. I would also suggest to optimize the image first. Try this [optimizer](https://tinypng.com), and this [converter](https://duri.me). I've been using those myself, and are quite good.

Comment: There are many online [image to CSS converter](https://imagetocss.com) tool. For example [imagetocss.com](https://imagetocss.com). Try this converter for further projects. Also, this site recommend to use Image not CSS, as Image is an SEO friendly source rather CSS can be used in only at the unexpected places